# Groovy How can change an XmlParser to an xml format?

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy

HI,
I've used XmlParser to can change the attributes of some nodes in my xml file.

Some code:

```
def temp = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "testAddress CUY#ResponseAsXML") 
def aux = temp.getXml();
def lang = new XmlParser().parseText(aux)
lang.prov[0].description[0].setValue('newDesciption')
```

After doing that I have something like

```
" root[attributes={}; value=[a[attributes={}; value=[1]], b[attributes={}; value=[ ]], c[attributes={}; value=[2]]]]"
```

How can I make it again to be an xml? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please fix the layout of your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
def out = new StringWriter()
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(out)).print(lang)
def xml = out.toString()
```